# Getting a strange error when using vpython

Tags: python, vpython

I want to start using vpython, and to check that it was installed correctly, I simply run a program importing it:

`import vpython`

While it does work, I get a strange error in the terminal about dividing by 0.

```
PS C:\Users\jaime\Documents\prueba_vpython> & C:/Users/jaime/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/jaime/Documents/prueba_vpython/vpythonintro.py
exit
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function Exit at 0x00000279931D4360>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vpython\vpython.py", line 22, in Exit
    a = 1.0/zero
        ~~~^~~~~
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
PS C:\Users\jaime\Documents\prueba_vpython>
```

I have no clue as to what it could be since I only run this line of code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try this instead, open a python REPL shell and there do a `import vpython`

Comment: It does work, but my issue is with Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: Your question does not reflect that, in your traceback you are running a Python module, please provide relevant traceback when running through Jupyter Notebook, also please check if the required module requires any config before running.